# Suppose $\ a,b\in\mathbb{Q}^+.\ $ Then $\ \exists\ c,d,k\in\mathbb{Z}^+,\ $ such that $\ a = \frac{c}{k},\ b = \frac{d}{k}\ $ and $\ \gcd(c,d,k)=1.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, problem-solving, alternative-proof, gcd-and-lcm

In various comments to answers of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610611/show-that-there-is-no-right-triangle-whose-legs-are-rational-numbers-and-whose-h/4610658), the following claim is made without proof. It seems to be true based on a few examples, but I can't quite prove it.

> Suppose $\ a,b\in\mathbb{Q}^+.\ $ Then $\ \exists\ c,d,k\in\mathbb{Z}^+,\ $ such that $\ a = \frac{c}{k},\ $ and $\ b =
> \frac{d}{k},\ $ and $\ \gcd(c,d,k) = 1.$

Here is my attempt to prove it:

There exists unique $\ w,x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}^+\ $ such that $\ a = \frac{w}{x},\ b = \frac{y}{z},\ $ and $\ \gcd(w,x) = \gcd(y,z) = 1.$

Then, I think that

$$\ a = \frac{ w\cdot \frac{z}{\gcd(x,z)} }{ x\cdot \frac{z}{\gcd(x,z)} },\quad b = \frac{ y\cdot \frac{x}{\gcd(x,z)} }{ z\cdot \frac{x}{\gcd(x,z)} } $$

solves the problem, because for some reason we should have:

$$ \gcd\left( \frac{wz}{\gcd(x,z)}, \frac{xz}{\gcd(x,z)}, \frac{yz}{\gcd(x,z)}\right) = 1.\quad (1) $$

However, I don't see an obvious way to prove $\ (1).\ $ I have observed that each of the terms of $\ (1)\ $ can be manipulated using the identity: $\ xz = \gcd(x,z) \cdot \text{lcm}(x,z),\ $ but I don't quite see how to make progress with this.

I also feel I am overlooking an alternative, more straightforward approach to the original claim...

Comment: If $a = \frac{m}{n}$ and $b = \frac{p}{q}$, then $a = \frac{mq}{nq}$ and $b = \frac{pn}{nq}$. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @kieransquared but then $\ \gcd(mq,nq,pn)\ $ is not necessarily $\ 1.\ $ For example, consider $\ a = \frac{5}{6},\ b = \frac{5}{9}.\ $ Then your approach gives us $\ \frac{45}{54}\ $ and $\ \frac{30}{54},\ $ all of which have $\ 3\ $ as a common factor.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: Nobody is requiring that the expressions be in least terms. In fact, usually they won't be. There is no way to write both $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ with a common denominator *and* in least terms.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that into the original question. I've added that in now. Although after a hasty closing of my question, I'm not sure it matters... Can you please re-open my question. Sorry, I forgot to add in that condition when I originally wrote my question.

Comment: $\text{gcd}(c,d,k) = 1$ is an important addition!

Comment: Yes I thought I wrote that when I first wrote the question, but I didn't. Sorry

Comment: For your edit: the least common denominator $\,k\,$ satisfies the gcd constraint (else $\,1<p\mid c,d,k\,$ so $p$ can be cancelled from both fractions $\,a = (c/p)/(k/p),\ b = (d/p)/(k/p),\,$ contra minimality of $k)\ \ $

Comment: **Update: now the dupe applies to the edited question also**. I added the prior comment to the linked dupe, so now it also applies to your edit (this is also mentioned elsewhere but likely difficult to find by search). But it fits naturally there too.